# Wrong JDK/JRE in Eclipse/Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a small project in Eclipse. I converted it into a Maven project. Everything went fine until I tried to use `ObjectOutputStream`. My colleague had a `writeInt()` method that he could use on an `ObjectOutputStream` object:

```
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
            socket.getOutputStream()));

os.writeInt(someInt);
```

I realised that Maven in my project has set the JDK version to 1.5. The method `writeInt()` is not aviable in `ObjectOutputStream` in JDK 1.5, but it is in 1.7.

Now some kind of chaos entered my project, it seems that it is using JDK 1.7, but I still cannot access the method... I tried everything but without effects... Is there any way to repair this problem?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong.`writeInt` existed for a long time!! Post the error message.
Here is a link to the method in Java 1.5 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeInt(int))

Comment: My bad, I haven't seen that the object I was working on was OutputStream, not ObjectOutputStream...

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) to set the source and target of the code, as seen below.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```